# Datatable does not allow to include multiple footers rows into exported excel file

Tags: javascript, excel, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to create a Datatable Excel file with multiple footers support with an export option.

But it's only created footer in a single cell with no multiple line support.

Kindly, let me know if it possible to create multiline footers in exported excel file? And if it then how to implement in javascript?

Or is it possible through with another workaround ?

I am sharing code

in JavaScript created datatable and add tfoot in a table

```
'<tfoot id="reportTblFoot' + chartIndex+ '">'+
'</tfoot>'
```

varible of table footer

```
var footer1 = $("<tr />");
```

Data append in footer

```
footer1.append(
    "<th>" +
    "<div style='font-style:italic;font-size:10px'>" +
    "* Applicable row 1<br>\n" +
    "** Not Applicable row 2<br>\n" +
    "*** Not Applicable row 3\n" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div>" +
    "<font size='1' color='grey'>**** Not Applicable row 4</font>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</th>"
);

footer1.append("<th style='display:none'/>");
footer1.append("<th style='display:none'/>");

$(tfoot).append(footer1);
```

In datatable properties apply TRUE for footer

```
buttons: [
{
extend: 'excel',
footer :true,
filename : fileName,
title : rprtTtl,
orientation: "landscape",
pageSize : "A3",
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of my own question

Here i require to replace data with new line (\n) and then return it into footer function. Actuality it a workaround to pass data in to footer

```
 exportOptions : {
                stripNewlines: false,
                format : {
                         footer : function (data, column, row){
                         console.log(data.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi,'\n'));
                         return data.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi,'\n');
                                                              }
                          }
                 },
```